# Node STRIDED_SLICE (number 48f) failed to prepare with status 1

Tags: tensorflow, pytorch, esp32, esp-idf, tflite

I am currently developing embedded software using the esp-idf framework for an AI model designed for image processing. The model, created in PyTorch, was trained with images in PNG format sized 512 x 512 x 3. The model's architecture expects to receive an image as a uint8_t array.

On the esp32 side I am running converted version of the model to tflite.

However, when attempting to initialize the model, I encounter the following error:

```
output_shape->data[shape_size] != dim_shape(1 != 0)
Node STRIDED_SLICE (number 48f) failed to prepare with status 1
```

I have tested "empty" model which does nothing to image and tensor allocation in memory after successful initialization seems ok, becouse the output tensor is being properly encoded back in to image.